# Elixir Docker multi-stage image file not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile, elixir

I create a simple Elixir app without Phoenix, I am able to run it without Docker.

When I want to dockerize the app using multi-stage build, I got an issue

```
/app/_build/prod/rel/todo_app/releases/0.1.0/../../erts-14.0.2/bin/erl: exec: line 12: /app/_build/prod/rel/todo_app/erts-14.0.2/bin/erlexec: not found
```

Here is the dockerfile

```
FROM elixir:1.15.1 as build

ENV MIX_ENV=prod

COPY lib ./lib
COPY mix.exs .
COPY mix.lock .

RUN mix local.hex --force && \
    mix local.rebar --force && \
    mix deps.get && \
    mix release

# Copy the production.env.exs file to the container
COPY config/prod.env.exs config/

# Final stage for the production release
FROM alpine:3.14

RUN apk add --no-cache bash openssl

WORKDIR /app

# Copy the release from the build stage
COPY --from=build . .

# Copy the Erlang runtime files
# COPY --from=build /app/_build/prod/rel/todo_app/erts-* /app/erts/

# Set the environment variables
ENV REPLACE_OS_VARS=true
ENV PORT=80
ENV MIX_ENV=prod

EXPOSE 80

# CMD ["ls", "_build/prod/rel/todo_app/erts-14.0.2/bin"]
CMD ["_build/prod/rel/todo_app/bin/todo_app", "start"]
```

But when I try with single stage, it is working.

single stage dockerfile

```
FROM elixir:1.15.1 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENV MIX_ENV=prod
COPY lib ./lib
COPY mix.exs .
COPY mix.lock .
COPY config/prod.env.exs config/

RUN mix local.rebar --force \
    && mix local.hex --force \
    && mix deps.get \
    && mix release

# ---- Application Stage ----
# RUN apk add --no-cache --update bash openssl
CMD ["_build/prod/rel/todo_app/bin/todo_app", "start"]
```

Help me what's wrong in my multi-stage dockerfile.

Comment: Have you tried uncommenting this line
`# COPY --from=builder /app/_build/prod/rel/todo_app/erts-* /app/erts/` and checking against the result you get from building now ?

Comment: The single-stage version of your dockerfile has `COPY . .` but the multistage version does not. Are you sure you're actually copying all of your source code? It's possible you have an unusual project structure and your source code is all in lib, but the error indicates a missing file.

Comment: That also could be the error message of `erlexec` having some shared-library dependencies that aren't present in the Alpine-based image.  You can find `erlexec` in `/usr/local/lib/erlang` in the `elixir` image and run `ldd` on it, though that doesn't suggest anything especially unusual.  Does using a `debian` or `ubuntu` base for the final image work better?

Comment: @Akki uncommenting that line is still resulting the same error

Comment: @DavidMaze tried it using ubuntu, I am getting different error message

Comment: @kusiaga can you share that error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run on Alpine, you should build on Alpine, too.

Try `FROM elixir:1.15.1-alpine as build` instead.

By the way, the [hexpm images](https://hub.docker.com/r/hexpm/elixir) are [more suitable](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/pull/2206) for Elixir development than the official images.